# $M$ Admitting A $\Bbb{Z}_n$-module structure and $Exp(M)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Corollary 7.7.16 An abelian group $M$ admits a $\Bbb{Z}_n$-module structure if and only if $M$ has exponent $n$ as a group.

This is something of a follow up to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676807/module-structure-induced-by-quotient-ring) My question is, is the theorem referring to **an** exponent of $M$ or **the** exponent? I ask because I don't see how to prove that $n$ is the exponent, only that it is an exponent.

Note that every abelian group, such as $M$, has a natural $\Bbb{Z}$-module structure that is unique. Assume that $M$ admits a $\Bbb{Z}_n = \Bbb{Z}/(n)$-module structure. Then by the theorem in the link, $(n) \subseteq \mbox{Ann}(M)$ which implies $nx = 0$ for all $x \in M$. I presume this means that $n$ is **an** exponent of $M$. But if the theorem is referring to **the** exponent, then I don't know how to show that $n$ is the exponent of $M$. Isn't the exponent whatever integer generates the ideal $\mbox{Ann}(M)$?

Comment: As i commented in the chat; for one direction, if you assume $M$ is an abelian group with exponent $n$ then the $\Bbb Z/(n)$-action given by $km = \bar{k}m$ (where $\bar{\cdot}$ denotes reduction modulo $n$) makes $M$ into a $\Bbb Z/(n)$-module. This is because $k = na + \bar{k}$ for some $a \in \Bbb Z$, by the division algorithm, and so $km = (na + \bar{k})m = (na)m + \bar{k}m = \bar{k}m$, since $n$ is the exponent of $M$. Now check the definition of module to show that this makes $M$ into a $\Bbb Z/(n)$-module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "an exponent", not "the exponent".  Indeed, the result is false for "the exponent": for instance, the trivial group has exponent $1$, but has a $\mathbb{Z}_n$-module structure for any $n$.